# backspace is not working in firefox for input when validation is applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, special-characters

I have written one function for the input validation using jquery which only allow to type characters and numbers. This is working fine in the chrome browser but when i am testing it in the firefox browser the backspace is not working...below is my function for the same.

```
noSpecialCharacther= function(fieldId) {
$('#' + fieldId).bind('keypress', function (event) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9 .()-]+$");
    var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
    if (!regex.test(key)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Please help me out with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `[\b]` the character class to match backspace.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#character-classes

```js
var noSpecialCharacther = function (fieldId) {

  $('#' + fieldId).on('keypress', function (event) {

    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9 .\b()-]+$");
    var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);

    if (!regex.test(key)) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }

  })

}

noSpecialCharacther('test')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="test">
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Its now working in the firefox browser